# Using Angular Paginator on Table with Data passed from parent

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am currently trying to figure out how to use the paginator and table from Angular Materials properly. I can display data but I have been trying to figure out for hours how to get the paginator to work.
As for my structure I have a parent component which contains a child component and passes data to it via @Input.

In my Parent-Component HTML:

```
 <div class="row"><app-export-preview [dataSource]="tableDataFilterResult"></app-export-preview></div>
```

In my Parent-Component TS I do a REST-Call and set my Data like this

```
  this.filterResult = response[0]['records'];
  this.tableDataFilterResult = new MatTableDataSource<any>(this.filterResult);
```

The REST-Call is called after a button, so basically the paginator and table exists before any data exists.

In my child component TS:

```
export class ExportPreviewComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {

  displayedColumns: string[] = ['number', 'name', 'reference', 'date', 'creator', 'coordinates', 'recordId'];

  @Input()
  dataSource: MatTableDataSource<any>;

  @ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator: MatPaginator;


  constructor() {

  }


  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.dataSource.data = this.dataSource.data;
  }
}
```

And my paginator in my child component HTML looks like this:

```
  <mat-paginator [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 20]" showFirstLastButtons></mat-paginator>
```

I am quite new to angular and i have tried for a while to find a solution. If anybody has any idea how to get the paginator to work, i would be thankful!

Comment: What is the issue? Have you tried using any mock data to the pagination?

Comment: Sorry I should have clarified better! I get data from the REST-Call and the data shows in the table. But the table should show 5 items per page as specified. Currently the data is just displayed as a lot of rows in the table. For some reason it seems like the paginator doesn't connect properly to the table? Mock data isn't going to help my issue as the communication with the REST-call should stay the same.

Comment: I have noticed you redundant code this.dataSource.data = this.dataSource.data; which will not be setting the data source in ngOnInit().

Comment: @Andrew Halil, if I pass the data from the parent object to the child how would I set the data source properly?

Comment: See my suggested solution. Pass the data source through the parent component, then set the child paginator control from calculated properties. Try that and see how you progress.

Answer (score 1):

To use a data source in your paginator you will need to pass a data source into the parent component first, then compute the length (total items) in your data source. Then you can set the parameters of the child pagination control.

Try something like this as a starting point:

```
export class ExportPreviewComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {

    _currentPage: number = 0;
    _numberOfPages: number;
    _itemsPerPage: number = 10;
    _totalItems: number;
    _dataSource: any;

    @ViewChild("paginator", {static: true}) paginator;

    get itemsPerPage() { return this._itemsPerPage; }
    get numberOfPages() { 
        return Math.ceil(this._totalItems / this._itemsPerPage); 
    }
    get currentPage() { return this._currentPage; }
    get totalItems() { return this._totalItems; }

    @Input("dataSource") 
    set dataSource(value: any) 
    { 
       this._dataSource = value; 
       this._totalItems = value.length;
    } 

    onSelect(value: PageEvent)
    {
        this._currentPage = this.paginator.pageIndex;
        this._numberOfPages = this.paginator.getNumberOfPages();
        this._itemsPerPage = this.paginator.pageSize;
    }


    ...
```

In your parent component html template (export-preview.component.html), set the child pagination component like this:

```
<mat-paginator  #paginator
            [length]="totalItems"
            [pageSize]="itemsPerPage"
            [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 25, 100]"
            (click)="onSelect($event)">
</mat-paginator>
```

For your parent component you can input the data source like this:

```
<app-export-preview
    [dataSource]=yourDataSource>
    .. 
</app-export-preview>
```

Where .. is whatever other parameters you want to pass into your parent component.

Answer (score 0):

According to Angular Material documentation, Mat-Paginator takes couple of predefined properties.

This is taken from example Stackblitz.

```
<mat-paginator [length]="100"
              [pageSize]="10"
              [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 25, 100]">
</mat-paginator>
```

To show 5 results per page, [pageSize]="5" binding should work.

Link to example Stackblitz:

[Paginator Example](http://%20https://stackblitz.com/angular/lvprgrknvvk?file=src/app/paginator-overview-example.html)